# Dynamic result update on the client side using Django framework

Tags: python, django, ipc, messaging

I have a remote machine running certain jobs. For every 5ms to 10ms the status of the job will change. I need to know the mechanism / module in python with which I would be able to see the status of the jobs running on my remote machine in the front end page developed using Django.

As I am new to this it would be a great help if you could point me some materials which help me to understand the mechanisms involved in the above question.

Comment: I am also looking for this. Will be good if any expert has answers for this.. Lets wait buddy !

Answer (score 0):

Try [django channels](http://channels.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

> Channels is a project to make Django able to handle more than just
>   plain HTTP requests, including WebSockets and HTTP2, as well as the
>   ability to run code after a response has been sent for things like
>   thumbnailing or background calculation.
>
> It’s an easy-to-understand extension of the Django view model, and
>   easy to integrate and deploy.

Other projects related to websockets https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/websockets/